# If received value isset, echo input field

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a search form on a webpage which i will create a dynamic page from the content in putted. I have got it to work but there is another one of these forms and there is also selectable data. I want it to only show the hidden fields lines when sku, sku2, txtKeyword2 is set. Please find below what i have tried so far.

```
<form name="frmSearch" method="get" action="<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']?>">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <th><h3>Search    </h3>
            <div class="alert-box">Insert Text for alert box</div>
        <input name="txtKeyword" type="text" id="txtKeyword" value="<?=$_GET["txtKeyword"];?>" size="40">
        <?php if(isset($_GET['sku'])) echo '<input type="hidden" name="sku" value="'.$_GET['sku'].'">'?>
        <?php if(isset($_GET['sku2'])) echo '<input type="hidden" name="sku2" value="'.$_GET['sku2'].'">'?>
        <?php if(isset($_GET['txtKeyword2'])) echo '<input type="hidden" name="txtKeyword2" value="'.$_GET['txtKeyword2'].'">'?>
        <input class="alert button" type="submit" value="Search"></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

All i want is for it not to show the input lines if they are not set. I think i am doing right but i am not sure as i am learning php.

I have also tried the following code which did work but it outputted the following url.

```
index.php?txtKeyword=giro%25skyline&sku=%09%09<input+type%3D
```

I know this shouldn't happen but it makes my page work but when i goto enter data in to the other search form it adds part of the input line in to the url. Here is the code that i tried:

```
<form name="frmSearch" method="get" action="<?=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']?>">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <th><h3>Search    </h3>
            <div class="alert-box">Insert text for the alert box</div>
        <input name="txtKeyword" type="text" id="txtKeyword" value="<?=$_GET["txtKeyword"];?>" size="40">
        <input type="hidden" name="sku" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['sku'])) echo ''.$_GET['sku'].'">'?>
        <input type="hidden" name="txtKeyword2" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['txtKeyword2'])) echo ''.$_GET['txtKeyword2'].'">'?>
        <input type="hidden" name="sku2" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['sku2'])) echo ''.$_GET['sku2'].'">'?>
        <input class="alert button" type="submit" value="Search"></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

I would really like to know what is going on how i can fix it.

Thanks Ryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php echo isset($_GET['sku']) ? '<input type="hidden" name="sku" value="'.$_GET['sku'].'">' : ''; ?>
```

However, just FYI, that is not secure at all.

For a start there is 2 likely vulnerabilities within that code:

1. XSS:
   if `$_GET['sku']` is something like: `"><script>alert('XSS');</script>`then you will get an alert box on your page, which in theory could be used for phishing, cookie stealing, creating a worm (like the SamiWorm). A good way to fix/prevent this is using [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities) which encodes all html characters into their associated entities.
2. SQL Injection:
   if `$_GET['sku']` is something like `' UNION ALL SELECT id,username,password FROM users LIMIT 0,1--` then you could potentially have your database stolen (especially if someone decided to use a tool like SQLMap, which is an automatic SQL Injection tool). A good way of fixing this is by using [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) on the argument which escapes any disallowed characters.

So a better way would be something like this:

```
 <?php echo isset($_GET['sku']) ? '<input type="hidden" name="sku" value="'.htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sku'])).'">' : ''; ?>
```

Here is why your code didn't work:

1. You were trying to make PHP evaluate your closing html tag : `">` inside your php echo will not work, as it will not know how to parse it.
2. It is easier to use ternary operators over short-ifs as, imho, they are easier to read/write for everyone else.

Here is my complete version:

```
<form name="frmSearch" method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>">
  <table width="100%">
    <tr>
      <th><h3>Search    </h3>
        <div class="alert-box">Insert text for the alert box</div>
        <input name="txtKeyword" type="text" id="txtKeyword" value="<?php echo isset($_GET["txtKeyword"]) ? htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["txtKeyword"]))) : ''; ?>" size="40">
        <input type="hidden" name="sku" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['sku']) ? htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sku'])) : ''; ?> ">
        <input type="hidden" name="txtKeyword2" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['txtKeyword2'])) ? htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['txtKeyword2'])); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="sku2" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['sku2']) ? htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sku2'])); ?> ">
        <input class="alert button" type="submit" value="Search"></th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi @DarkMantis This worked I know about SQL Injection but this is not going to be used by anyone other than my self and if we were going to release it we will protect our dba

Comment: Okay I've fixed my answer @Prix. I wrote it in a bit of a rush, so I didn't include the reasons, but you're right, that's no excuse :)

Comment: @RyanThomasKing as a side note your php seems to have `short_open_tag = Off` which does not let you use the `<?=` so you have to either enable it on your `php.ini` or use `<?php echo $variable; ?>` instead.

Comment: @Prix actually if you use `<?=` it should be fine, as that invokes it to be printed. As `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];` is not self-printing then it requires an echo/print or the `<?=`. You may not have short-hand opening tags enabled on your PHP install. Also your example wouldn't have worked as you would require an echo too. <?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?> Example here: http://codepad.org/yLgk4WA2

Comment: Sorry Just realized that you changed your comment xD Now mine looks a little bit irrelevant

Comment: Ah right it might have been that I was looking at, It's alright it can stay there in case it helps anyone in the future :) Don't think I was trying to flame you or anything, I was just trying to explain it to anyone else who may read this